# Restricting input in angular component

Tags: angular

I am wondering if there is a recommended "Angular" way to restrict inputs so that when a component is used by another developer they know that they are using wrong combination of inputs or events on the component. For example:

We have a component fruit which takes two inputs [first] and [second], we need to restrict other developers to either pass [first] or [second] but not both at the same time.

```
<fruit [first]="'apple'"  /> // THIS IS VALID
<fruit [second]="'orange'" /> // THIS IS VALID
<fruit [first]="'apple'" [second]="'orange'" /> // THIS IS NOT VALID
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a simple and easy way to achieve that. The **input** parameters are available by the **Init** lifecycle hook. So you can create an **out** parameter with **EventEmitter** to emit (error / or some flag) to indicate that wrong combination of input parameters are provided. So for example your component has following **Input** and **Output** parameters.

```
  @Input()
  public first: string;

  @Input()
  public second: string;

  @Output()
  public wrongeParameters:EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

Your ngOnInit method would look like this

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
  if(this.first && this.second) //if both parameters are provided.
  {
    this.wrongeParameters.emit('Both first and second parameters can not be provided');
  }
  }
```

And your parent component can handle the **wrongParameters** event like this

```
<fruit [first]="'Apple'" [second]="'Banana'" (wrongeParameters)="wrongeParameter($event)"></fruit>
```

The method would get called on parent component like this

```
  wrongeParameter(error: string)
  {
    console.log(error);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, this is a good idea but i feel like there has to be a better way to do this, i really do not want to add an extra event handler just for the wrongParameters. May be if developer uses illegal inputs, as soon as they compile code, developer should be able to see an error or at least a warning in console window

Comment: There could be many other ways other than EventEmitter approach e.g. create a subjectBehavior that emits error when both values are initialized, you could define a directive and show an error, but showing error at compile time is I guess beyond the scope, or at least I've no idea if its possible at all ?